# calling var that is function

Tags: jquery, function, setinterval, var

I have this script and need to be able to call the $play variable as a function i.e. restart the set interval the pause function works fine but I can't get it to restart on clicking play.

```
    if( itemsCount > 1 ) {
        // addNavigation
        var $navPlay= $('body').find('.play'),
        $navPause= $('body').find('.pause'),
        $imgWrapper= $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image'),
        $play = window.setInterval(function(){
            _navigate('right');
        }, 500);

        $navPlay.on('click', function( event ) {
            $play;
            return false;
        });

        $navPause.on('click', function( event ) {
            clearInterval($play);
            return false;
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: `$play` here isn't a function, it's an identifier for the interval you've set.

Comment: how do i use the identifier to call the function?

Comment: you don't. The interval has been set when you called setInterval, and his now called every 500ms to execute `_navigate`. So I assume what you want is a way to reactivate this interval on demand (when you receive a click, here)?

Comment: yes spot on sorry i don't know the right terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't exactly had the time to create an example to replicate something similar to your use case, but something along these lines should do.

```
    function starter() {
        return (window.setInterval(function () {
            _navigate('right');
        }, 500));
    }

    // stuff
    if( itemsCount > 1 ) {
            // addNavigation
            var $navPlay        = $('body').find('.play'),
                $navPause       = $('body').find('.pause'),
                $imgWrapper     = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image'),
                $play           = starter(); // auto-start (set to null if not desired)

            $navPlay.on('click', function( event ) {
                if (!$play) { // probably don't want to set this twice
                  $play = starter();
                }
                return false;
            });

            $navPause.on('click', function( event ) {
                if ($play) {
                    clearInterval($play);
                    $play = null;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }           
    // stuff
```

Comment: My way still allows you to use the variable :) But great answer!

Comment: @Shawn31313: there's a slight danger with yours though: calling `$play` will override the previous `timeout`, so you won't be able to release it if you didn't before hand (would be a programmer error, just as it would be one with mine to not capture the return and then not be able to release either, but I prefer it that way).

Comment: True(: Well eh could you at least up mine :)

Comment: oh ok...well i like your too. so +1 for you. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a variable as a function then just use `function(){}`

```
if (itemsCount > 1) {
    // addNavigation
    var timeout,
        $navPlay = $('body').find('.play'),
        $navPause = $('body').find('.pause'),
        $imgWrapper = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image'),
        $play = function () {
            timeout = window.setInterval(function () {
                _navigate('right');
            }, 500);
        };

    $navPlay.on('click', function (event) {
        $play();
        return false;
    });

    $navPause.on('click', function (event) {
        clearInterval(timeout);
        return false;
    });
}
```

You can add variables in the parentheses just like a normal function and it works great. Also give you timeout a separate variable which you can globally.